# Идентификация узлов вычислительной системы

Tags: графы, сеть

Привет всем!)
Есть такая проблемка, может на нее уже существует алгоритм...
Вообщем, есть связный неориентированный граф. Все ребра имеют пропускную способность. Вершины это ЭВМ.
Задача вот в чем, нужно пронумеровать каждую вершину этого графа(присвоить номер каждому ЭВМ). Понятно что петель и кратных ребер нет)
Подскажите алгоритм, может уже проблему решали?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если то, что я понял, это нужно пройти по вершинам и все пронумеровать, то вам могут помочь алгоритмы BFS и DFS. Каждый из них обходит граф, только один это делает в глубину, а другой в ширину. Вот вам и способ пронумеровать все вершины.